# How to extract sub string between two spaces

Tags: r, regex

I have string as

> "Air transport     9964 1602869084038          RFND          01-Nov-18
>   NON        CX07/1819/071443     30-Sep-18    239982.00     10071.00
>   0.00%     0.00 0.00%      0.00   12.00 28798.00      0%       0.00   278851.00"

I want to extract `239982.00` which i know comes between 8th and 9th space
so output should be `239982.00`

i tried by giving index of `239982.00`  by storing all entries in one list and taking nth element using `lst[n]` but in this solution the problem is that order is not fixed in all of the strings

lst2[53]

Comment: I think it is actually between 9th and 10th space in the given string

Comment: Sorry in a hurry I Quoted wrong positions in subject line

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "Air transport 9964 1602869084038 RFND 01-Nov-18 NON CX07/1819/071443 30-Sep-18 239982.00 10071.00 0.00% 0.00 0.00% 0.00 12.00 28798.00 0% 0.00 278851.00"
i = 9
j = 10
ind = gregexpr(pattern = " ", text = x)[[1]]
substring(text = x, first = ind[i] + 1, last = ind[j] - 1)
#[1] "239982.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `sub` to capture the non-white space character after the 9th occurrence of non white space followed by white space characterss (`(\\S+\\s+){9})`

```
sub("((\\S+\\s+){9})(\\S+).*", "\\3", x)
#[1] "239982.00"
```

---

Or more compactly with `word`

```
library(stringr)
word(x, 10)
#[1] "239982.00"
```

#### data

```
x <-  "Air transport 9964 1602869084038 RFND 01-Nov-18 NON CX07/1819/071443 30-Sep-18 239982.00 10071.00 0.00% 0.00 0.00% 0.00 12.00 28798.00 0% 0.00 278851.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strsplit(x,' ')[[1]][10]
# [1] "239982.00"
```

or, more generally in case x is a vector:

```
sapply(strsplit(x,' '), `[`, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `read.table`:

```
text = "Air transport 9964 1602869084038 RFND 01-Nov-18 NON CX07/1819/071443 30-Sep-18 239982.00 10071.00 0.00% 0.00 0.00% 0.00 12.00 28798.00 0% 0.00 278851.00"

read.table(text = text)$V10
# [1] 239982
```

or

```
read.table(text = text)[,10]
# [1] 239982
```